# Collection View Items can't Bind on FileInfo type. [Xamarin Forms]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'am trying to bind my collection view on a list of FileInfo

For example :

```
List<FileInfo> files = FileHelper.GetFiles();
collectionViewList.ItemsSource = files;
```

But I have an error : "Specified cast is invalid"

If am trying to do this on a simple list view it work.

Maybe collection view doesn't accept somes type of objects ?

Code Used when the exeption is raise :

```
 private async void StartProcessButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (MyListView.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (this.selectedItemId)
        {
            case 0:
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new ConcatePdfPage(fileInfo));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

I tried debuging and when my app is loading my concate page the exeption is raise at this line of code :

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new ConcatePdfPage(fileInfo));
```

My constructor class :

```
public ConcatePdfPage(FileInfo fileInfo)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.fileInfo1 = fileInfo;

            IPdfPickerAndroid pdfPickerAndroid = DependencyService.Get<IPdfPickerAndroid>();

            FilesList.ItemsSource = pdfPickerAndroid.GetPdfFilesInDocuments();
        }
```

To be more precise the errors is raise when my collection view is loading, binding to the ***List of FileInfo ***

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8

But I tried to bind my collection view on a list of string.

And it work, no exeption is raise.

I also tried to bind my list of FileInfo on a list view instead of a collection view and no exeption was raise.

Comment: What does the stack trace show?  Are you sure the error isn't happening on the first line?  Or that one of the bindings in your ItemTemplate isn't causing it?

Comment: @Jason I added new images When my app is loading the page the problem is raise

Comment: First, please do NOT post code as images.  Second, I have no idea what they are supposed to show.  They don't address any of the questions I asked

Comment: My apologize @Jason

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :

I deleted the viewcell attributes in my xaml code on the page where the exeption is raise.

```
<CollectionView x:Name="FilesList" SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding CreationTime.Date, StringFormat='{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

New code :

```
<CollectionView x:Name="FilesList" SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding CreationTime.Date, StringFormat='{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

https://medium.com/a-developer-in-making/how-to-work-with-collectionview-in-xamarin-forms-5dc65c50b419

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue by yourself, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.